# The URL param 'tags' is ignored when the 'show' param is not present

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

When I am on the home screen and I click on one of my favorite tags, it takes me to this URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/?show=all&sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=perl

Now when I click the "new" link in the tabs (next to "popular" and "need answer"), it takes me here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/?layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=perl

[image: this link has the second URL]

Both of them have the `tags=perl` and `layout=expanded`. The new page does not show the filter box though, and the results are not only questions with the tag *perl*. If I manually add the param `show=all` however, the filter box appears and the results get filtered down to only questions with my tag.

[image: The next page still has the tags=perl but there is no filtering]

---

Showing less questions when the param says show all of them is strange indeed. Also it's impractical.

Answer (score 1):

The bug was actually due to the impossibility of filtering that view by tag. It should now work.